# Shopware 6 Get all sales channels

Tags: shopware6

I want to get all sales channel from shopware 6 and perform some actions on it. For the actions i need the salesChannelsId. But how do i get this?

I've created a subscriber, which is waiting for the `PRODUCT_WRITTEN_EVENT`  and is then performing actions in my Service.

```php
namespace Me\MyPlugin\Subscriber;

use Me\MyPlugin\Service\MyService;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityWrittenEvent;

class ProductUpdatedSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private myService $myService;

    public function __construct(MyService $myService)
    {
        $this->myService = $myService;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductEvents::PRODUCT_WRITTEN_EVENT => 'onProductUpdated'
        ];
    }

    public function onProductUpdated(EntityWrittenEvent $event): void
    {
        $this->myService->updateIndex();
    }
}
```

And in my service i want to get all sales channels and perform further actions.

```php
 public function updateIndex(): void
    {
        $salesChannelId = null;
        $shouldSync = $this->configService->get('Index.syncSalesChannels', $salesChannelId);
        if (!$shouldSync) {
            return;
        }

        $salesChannels = --/ how to get all salesChannels?
        foreach ($salesChannels as $salesChannelId) {
            $products = $this->fetchActiveProducts($salesChannelId);
            $this->sendToX($products, $salesChannelId);
        }
    }
```

Now i'm out of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject the `sales_channel.repository` service into your index service and then perform a search to fetch the sales channels from the database.

Take a look at [the docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/reading-data) for more information on how to achieve that.